# The layouts of two different devices (Samsung Galaxy S4 mini & Sony Xperia Z1) looks in some placed different. Why?

Tags: android, layout

I have made a one layout (layout-sw360dp) for the devices Sony Xperia Z1 and Samsung Galaxy mini. Both take the layout-sw360dp when started.

And I have a third device LG Optimus 7, this device take the default layout.

In most cases the layouts for the three diveces looks fine. But in one case it do something different. 
I had implement a Sliding panel from here [GitHub Umano Sliding Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).  And this looks fine on the LG Optimus 7 on default layout. Here a snaped picture:

[image]

They gray area is the Sliding panel which is expaned. And the yellow are is a button. when the panel is not expanded the button is on bottom of layout. When the panel expand it goes up. This works well on the default layout, like I said.

But on the two other devices which use the layout-sw360dp it doesnt work well. Here a picture of the **Sony Xperia Z1**:

[image]

The two "areas" cut across.

And here a picture of the **Samsung Galaxy S4 mini**:

[image]

There is a gap between the areas. But I really have no idea how this happens.

Maybe I should use a other layout define?

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try using layout-xxhdpi for whatever you are doing in layout-sw360dp.